# "error: unknown type name 'PyObject'" when using C extension on python

Tags: python, c

I was trying to write a selection sort C program for an array that could be run using python commands.  This is what I have in my C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int selectionsort(array[], N){
    int i, j, min_element;
    
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        min_element = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        if (array[j] < array[min_element])
        min_element = j;
        int temp = array[min_element];
        array[min_element] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    
    printf("Sorted array: ");
    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        if (i != N-1){
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("]");
    return 0;
}

static PyObject* selectSort(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int array[20000];
    int N = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &array, &N))
        return NULL;
    return Py_BuildValue("i", selectionsort(array, N));
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    { "selectSort", selectSort, METH_VARARGS, "selectSort" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myModule",
    "Test Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myModule(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&myModule);
}
```

This is what I have in my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name = 'myModule', version = '1.0',  \
   ext_modules = [Extension('myModule', ['selectSort.c'])])
```

However, when I was trying to build using terminal command line, it gave me 12 errors, an example will be:
`selectSort.c:28:8: error: unknown type name 'PyObject' static PyObject* selectSort(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)`

How come it does not know what is PyObject? Anyone has any ideas on how to solve it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: you need to include <python.h> which defines PyObject and other python classes.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get another error:
`selectSort.c:43:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT'
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,`
Which seems to be something wrong with my module delcaration?

Comment: i think you are including the system version of python.h which happens to be python2.x instead of python3.x , and your code can only work with python3.x headers, you have to change it to work with python2.x headers if that's your objective.

Comment: or include the proper python.h header file of your python3.x interpreter.

Comment: Is it possible to change my header to python3.x?